# Want to call signalr hub server from .net client and hub server will call web client to update

Tags: javascript, .net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

my .net client code is:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/signalrServer");
            IHubProxy myproxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            //hubConnection.ma
            myproxy.Invoke("JoinGroup", "MapRoom");

            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                myproxy.Invoke("callFromService", new Random().NextDouble().ToString());
            }
```

my signal hub server code:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
public void CallFromService(string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            //Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);


        }
}
```

my web client code is

```
 $(function () {
            debugger;
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            //chat.logging = true;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
                debugger;
                angular.element(document.getElementById('mapdiv')).scope().$apply(function (scope) {
                    scope.mapMsg = message;
                });

            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                debugger;
                //chat.server.joinGroup("MapRoom");
            });

        });
```

This code able to work on only one web client
if i am opening same page on new tab or new browser its stuck.
when i closed one tab then its working...

I want server to update all web clients.

Comment: i have tried : GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>().Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message); (its not working)

Comment: Where are you hosting your web site? If it is behind some sort of load balancer, there's a chance you are not connecting to the same node on both tabs and unless you have a backplane the messages aren't synced across nodes.